# Rails expire low level cache on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails low level cache in my controller but I don't know how to expire the cache when record is updated. Below is snippets of my controller

```
def show
  @user = Rails.cache.fetch("users/params[:id]", expires_in: 2.minutes) do
     User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

So rails is creating cache fine. But when I update the record I want to expire old cache and create new one. e.g

```
User.first.touch
```

I found that rails have `cache_key_with_version` but I am not sure how to use that with my example

```
@user = User.first
@user.cache_key_with_version #=> "users/1-20220316023452830286"
```

I won't have `@user` object at the first call in my controller so I am not sure how to use `@user.cache_key_with_version` as my key.

```
@user = Rails.cache.fetch(@user.cache_key_with_version)
```

Above code will not work as `@user` is `nil` at this stage.

One way I can think of is use `after_save` callback in model to delete cache key on save. Some thing like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :delete_cache_key

  private

  def delete_cache_key
    Rails.cache.delete("users/#{self.id}")
  end
end
```

But may be there is better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Rails to get expired when record update, add `cache_key_with_version` to your cache key, so the controller will be like

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  Rails.cache.fetch("users/#{@user.cache_key_with_version}", expires_in: 2.minutes) do
     # some other query that need to be done
  end
end
```

loading a record should not be a heavy load, if it is, than use `.select(:id, :updated_at)` may be a choice

```
def show
  user_cache_key = User.select(:id, :updated_at).find(params[:id]).cache_key_with_version
  @user = Rails.cache.fetch("users/#{user_cache_key}", expires_in: 2.minutes) do
     User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

cache key is made with updated_at and id, so we only these two column to make a cache key with version. When record update, it will update updated_at, too, the previous cache will be discarded

Comment: With this approach it will always hit database to find user details. I still think it's better to delete cache key using `after_save` call back. I don't want to hit database if cache is already there, but with this approach i will be hitting database even when  cache is available.